# Resultset values are being updated in other transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have observed strange behaviour with SQL Server and JDBC - related to large select distinct query and batch updates.

What do we have is a not-so-big (around 2M rows) table which consists of large amount of nvarchar stored numbers. There is nonclustered index with this column only. I'm selecting all distincts values, and performing updates on these values in batch packages.

However, it seems like sometimes updated values are reflected into returned resultSet.

Example code:

```
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(3);
    config.setAutoCommit(false);
    final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
    final Connection selectConn = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
    final PreparedStatement selectStmt = selectConn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT A FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE A IS NOT NULL", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    final ResultSet resultSet = selectStmt.executeQuery();
    do {
        List<String> valuesToUpdate = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000 && resultSet.next(); i++) {
            final String valueToUpdate = resultSet.getString(1);
            valuesToUpdate.add(valueToUpdate);
            if (valueToUpdate.equals("31081273963")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("This should be never thrown.");
            }
        }

        if (valuesToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        Connection updateConn = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
        final PreparedStatement batchStatement = updateConn.prepareStatement("UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE SET A = '31081273963' WHERE A = ?");
        for (String str: valuesToUpdate) {
            batchStatement.setObject(1, str);
            batchStatement.addBatch();
        }
        batchStatement.executeBatch();
        updateConn.commit();
        updateConn.close();
    } while (true);
```

In above example, "31081273963" is 100% guaranteed not to be in database before code execution. I'm setting all received values to this "31081273963" value. But sometimes I run into this `if (valueToUpdate.equals("31081273963"))` condition.

The strangest thing is that I can get this Exception with example value of "31081273963", which is somewhat in the middle of ordered query (when it would be in the table), but when I pick value closer to begining, no exception is thrown. (Of course I'm not telling that this value is 'special', but what I mean is that I have to pick a value which is not at the begining of result set in order to cause this exception.

Is this behaviour somewhat documented, or is relying on some kind of parameter? Is SQL Server extending DISTINCT query results "on the fly" with new values? If yes, why it does only for later values?

(Real XY problem - make resultSet untouched for full scrolling, with updates in background, but without locking the table - but I'm just curious why and when this issue occurs.)

Comment: I suspect some problem with isolation level in the connection. It could be having READ UNCOMMITTED. Or see whether the way CURSOR is setup is not reading tables from the disk. Need to dig into the JDBC cursor behaviour here. Or you can go for UPDATEABLE cursors and update there itself, instead of two connections.

Comment: Also, see as you are using same connection between UPDATE and SELECT, does it cause any problem